# Only one part of my HTML breaks at a time

Tags: css, html

```css
label {
    width:180px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:15px;
}

select, textarea, input, label {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>


<head>
<title>World Wind Helicopters Online Hour Sheet
</title>
<style>



</style>

</head>
<body>

<form action="data.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
 <select id="name" name="slname"/>
 <option>Name
 <option>Name
 <option>Name
 <option>Name
 <option>Name
 <option>Name
 <option>Name
 </select>


<br>

<label for="date">Date:</label>
 <input id="date" type="date" name="date"/>

<br>

<label for="Location">Location:</label>
 <input id="Location" type="text" name="txtlocation" value="Enter Location Here"/>

<br>

<label for="Type">Type:</label>
  <select id="Type" name="sltype">
  <option>USFS</option>
  <option>91</option>
  <option>133</option>
  <option>135</option>
  </select>
<br>
<label for="Helicopter">Helicopter:</label>
 <select id="Helicopter" name="rdheli">
  <option>N510WW</option>
  <option>N610WW</option>
  <option>N205WW</option>
  <option>N350WW</option>


<label for="DTO">Duty Time On:</label>
 <select id="DTO" name="sldutyon">
  <option>1:00</option>
  <option>2:00</option>
  <option>3:00</option>
  <option>4:00</option>
  <option>5:00</option>
  <option>6:00</option>
  <option>7:00</option>
  <option>8:00</option>
  <option>9:00</option>
  <option>10:00</option>
  <option>11:00</option>
  <option>12:00</option>
  <option>13:00</option>
  <option>14:00</option>
  <option>15:00</option>
  <option>16:00</option>
  <option>17:00</option>
  <option>18:00</option>
  <option>19:00</option>
  <option>20:00</option>
  <option>21:00</option>
  <option>22:00</option>
  <option>23:00</option>
  <option>0:00</option>
  </select>
  
  
<label for="DTOFF">Duty Time Off:</label> 
 <select id="DTOFF" name="sldutyoff">
  <option>1:00</option>
  <option>2:00</option>
  <option>3:00</option>
  <option>4:00</option>
  <option>5:00</option>
  <option>6:00</option>
  <option>7:00</option>
  <option>8:00</option>
  <option>9:00</option>
  <option>10:00</option>
  <option>11:00</option>
  <option>12:00</option>
  <option>13:00</option>
  <option>14:00</option>
  <option>15:00</option>
  <option>16:00</option>
  <option>17:00</option>
  <option>18:00</option>
  <option>19:00</option>
  <option>20:00</option>
  <option>21:00</option>
  <option>22:00</option>
  <option>23:00</option>
  <option>0:00</option>
  </select>  
  
  
  

<br>

<label for="FT">Flight Time:</label>
 <input id="FT" type="text" name="txtflighttime"/>

<br>


<label for="Duty Time">Duty Time:</label>
 <input id="Duty Time" type="text" name="txtdutytime"/>
<br>

<label for="Day Landing">Day Landings:</label>
 <input id="Day Landing" type="text" name="txtdayland"/>
<br>

<label for="Night Landing">Night Landings:</label>
 <input id="Night Landing" type="text" name="txtnightland"/>
<br>

<label for="Night Time">Night Time:</label>
 <input id="Night Time" type="text" name="txtnighttime"/>
<br>

<label for="Long Line">Long Line:</label>
 <input id="Long Line" type="text" name="txtlongline"/>
<br>

<label for="Tanker Loads">Tanker Loads:</label>
 <input id="Tanker Loads" type="text" name="txttankload"/>
<br>

<label for="Mountain">Mountain:</label>
 <input id="Mountain" type="text" name="txtmtn"/>
<br>
<label for="Comments">Comments:</label>
 <textarea id="Comments" name="txtarcomments" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">   
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

Only that select menu is breaking, I can't figure out what is causing it.
If I switch the order of the inputs and selects, only one ends up breaking.Does anyone know what is causing this? Also I know my HTML is messy, sorry.

Comment: As everyone is pointing out, you didn't close your tags, but you also have a self-closing tag that shouldn't be there... '<select id="name" name="slname"/>'

Comment: If you are still learning and making these kind of mistakes, you should probably use validator more https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to close some tags.
Some options and a select tag.

```css
label {
    width:180px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:15px;
}

select, textarea, input, label {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>


<head>
<title>World Wind Helicopters Online Hour Sheet
</title>
<style>



</style>

</head>
<body>

<form action="data.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
 <select id="name" name="slname">
 <option>Vince Lopardo</option>
 <option>Jay Ferguson</option>
 <option>Kent Pierce</option>
 <option>Jason Reschke</option>
 <option>Dan Rudert</option>
 <option>David Kerr</option>
 <option>Rick Dominy</option>
 </select>


<br>

<label for="date">Date:</label>
 <input id="date" type="date" name="date"/>

<br>

<label for="Location">Location:</label>
 <input id="Location" type="text" name="txtlocation" value="Enter Location Here"/>

<br>

<label for="Type">Type:</label>
  <select id="Type" name="sltype">
  <option>USFS</option>
  <option>91</option>
  <option>133</option>
  <option>135</option>
  </select>
<br>
<label for="Helicopter">Helicopter:</label>
 <select id="Helicopter" name="rdheli">
  <option>N510WW</option>
  <option>N610WW</option>
  <option>N205WW</option>
  <option>N350WW</option>
</select>


<label for="DTO">Duty Time On:</label>
 <select id="DTO" name="sldutyon">
  <option>1:00</option>
  <option>2:00</option>
  <option>3:00</option>
  <option>4:00</option>
  <option>5:00</option>
  <option>6:00</option>
  <option>7:00</option>
  <option>8:00</option>
  <option>9:00</option>
  <option>10:00</option>
  <option>11:00</option>
  <option>12:00</option>
  <option>13:00</option>
  <option>14:00</option>
  <option>15:00</option>
  <option>16:00</option>
  <option>17:00</option>
  <option>18:00</option>
  <option>19:00</option>
  <option>20:00</option>
  <option>21:00</option>
  <option>22:00</option>
  <option>23:00</option>
  <option>0:00</option>
  </select>
  
  
<label for="DTOFF">Duty Time Off:</label> 
 <select id="DTOFF" name="sldutyoff">
  <option>1:00</option>
  <option>2:00</option>
  <option>3:00</option>
  <option>4:00</option>
  <option>5:00</option>
  <option>6:00</option>
  <option>7:00</option>
  <option>8:00</option>
  <option>9:00</option>
  <option>10:00</option>
  <option>11:00</option>
  <option>12:00</option>
  <option>13:00</option>
  <option>14:00</option>
  <option>15:00</option>
  <option>16:00</option>
  <option>17:00</option>
  <option>18:00</option>
  <option>19:00</option>
  <option>20:00</option>
  <option>21:00</option>
  <option>22:00</option>
  <option>23:00</option>
  <option>0:00</option>
  </select>  
  
  
  

<br>

<label for="FT">Flight Time:</label>
 <input id="FT" type="text" name="txtflighttime"/>

<br>


<label for="Duty Time">Duty Time:</label>
 <input id="Duty Time" type="text" name="txtdutytime"/>
<br>

<label for="Day Landing">Day Landings:</label>
 <input id="Day Landing" type="text" name="txtdayland"/>
<br>

<label for="Night Landing">Night Landings:</label>
 <input id="Night Landing" type="text" name="txtnightland"/>
<br>

<label for="Night Time">Night Time:</label>
 <input id="Night Time" type="text" name="txtnighttime"/>
<br>

<label for="Long Line">Long Line:</label>
 <input id="Long Line" type="text" name="txtlongline"/>
<br>

<label for="Tanker Loads">Tanker Loads:</label>
 <input id="Tanker Loads" type="text" name="txttankload"/>
<br>

<label for="Mountain">Mountain:</label>
 <input id="Mountain" type="text" name="txtmtn"/>
<br>
<label for="Comments">Comments:</label>
 <textarea id="Comments" name="txtarcomments" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">   
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to close select tag

```
<label for="Helicopter">Helicopter:</label>
<select id="Helicopter" name="rdheli">
    <option>N510WW</option>
    <option>N610WW</option>
    <option>N205WW</option>
    <option>N350WW</option>
</select> <!--this select tag is missing in your code-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a select tag for helicopter.

Answer (score -1):

select is not closed.

```
<html>


<head>
<title>World Wind Helicopters Online Hour Sheet
</title>
<style>



</style>

</head>
<body>

<form action="data.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
    <select id="name" name="slname"/>
    <option>Vince Lopardo
    <option>Jay Ferguson
    <option>Kent Pierce
    <option>Jason Reschke
    <option>Dan Rudert
    <option>David Kerr
    <option>Rick Dominy
    </select>


<br>

<label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input id="date" type="date" name="date"/>

<br>

<label for="Location">Location:</label>
    <input id="Location" type="text" name="txtlocation" value="Enter Location Here"/>

<br>

<label for="Type">Type:</label>
        <select id="Type" name="sltype">
        <option>USFS</option>
        <option>91</option>
        <option>133</option>
        <option>135</option>
        </select>
<br>
<label for="Helicopter">Helicopter:</label>
    <select id="Helicopter" name="rdheli">
        <option>N510WW</option>
        <option>N610WW</option>
        <option>N205WW</option>
        <option>N350WW</option>
        </select>

<label for="DTO">Duty Time On:</label>
    <select id="DTO" name="sldutyon">
        <option>1:00</option>
        <option>2:00</option>
        <option>3:00</option>
        <option>4:00</option>
        <option>5:00</option>
        <option>6:00</option>
        <option>7:00</option>
        <option>8:00</option>
        <option>9:00</option>
        <option>10:00</option>
        <option>11:00</option>
        <option>12:00</option>
        <option>13:00</option>
        <option>14:00</option>
        <option>15:00</option>
        <option>16:00</option>
        <option>17:00</option>
        <option>18:00</option>
        <option>19:00</option>
        <option>20:00</option>
        <option>21:00</option>
        <option>22:00</option>
        <option>23:00</option>
        <option>0:00</option>
        </select>


<label for="DTOFF">Duty Time Off:</label>   
    <select id="DTOFF" name="sldutyoff">
        <option>1:00</option>
        <option>2:00</option>
        <option>3:00</option>
        <option>4:00</option>
        <option>5:00</option>
        <option>6:00</option>
        <option>7:00</option>
        <option>8:00</option>
        <option>9:00</option>
        <option>10:00</option>
        <option>11:00</option>
        <option>12:00</option>
        <option>13:00</option>
        <option>14:00</option>
        <option>15:00</option>
        <option>16:00</option>
        <option>17:00</option>
        <option>18:00</option>
        <option>19:00</option>
        <option>20:00</option>
        <option>21:00</option>
        <option>22:00</option>
        <option>23:00</option>
        <option>0:00</option>
        </select>       




<br>

<label for="FT">Flight Time:</label>
    <input id="FT" type="text" name="txtflighttime"/>

<br>


<label for="Duty Time">Duty Time:</label>
    <input id="Duty Time" type="text" name="txtdutytime"/>
<br>

<label for="Day Landing">Day Landings:</label>
    <input id="Day Landing" type="text" name="txtdayland"/>
<br>

<label for="Night Landing">Night Landings:</label>
    <input id="Night Landing" type="text" name="txtnightland"/>
<br>

<label for="Night Time">Night Time:</label>
    <input id="Night Time" type="text" name="txtnighttime"/>
<br>

<label for="Long Line">Long Line:</label>
    <input id="Long Line" type="text" name="txtlongline"/>
<br>

<label for="Tanker Loads">Tanker Loads:</label>
    <input id="Tanker Loads" type="text" name="txttankload"/>
<br>

<label for="Mountain">Mountain:</label>
    <input id="Mountain" type="text" name="txtmtn"/>
<br>
<label for="Comments">Comments:</label>
    <textarea id="Comments" name="txtarcomments" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">            
</form>



</body>

</html>
```